# Работа с файлом (Проверка и запись/чтение)

Tags: c#

Стоит концепция, при запуске создается `txt` файл в директории с документами. Туда записывается `токен`, и при следующем запуске происходит проверка:

`если файл существует - вывести сообщение или создать файл и записать в него токен`

Я уверен что все верно, но не могу понять почему появляется ошибка, мол файл уже занят другим процессом, и не дает записать/прочитать себя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

**EDIT**

```
            var username = Environment.UserName;
            var date = Environment.TickCount;
            var id = Environment.UserName;

            string token_param = "123456789";
            int token_lenght = 6;
            string token_result = "";

            //Создание объекта для генерации чисел
            Random rnd = new Random();

            StreamWriter token = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\token.txt");

            int token_lng = token_param.Length;

            var path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\token.txt";
            var exist = File.Exists(path);
            Console.WriteLine(exist);

            if (exist == true)
            {
                string content = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\token.txt");
                Console.WriteLine("Current content of file:");
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }

            else if (exist == false)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < token_lenght; i++)
                {
                    File.Create("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\token.txt");
                    token.Flush();
                    token_result += token_param[rnd.Next(token_lng)];
                    token.WriteLine(token_result);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n {0}", token_result);
```

Comment: возможно вы просто паралельно открыли файл, с которым работаете

Comment: Я нашёл проблему. Лишней была строка `StreamWriter token = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\token.txt");`, поток открывался и оставался открытым - в итоге он и считался занятым кем-то другим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StreamWriter token = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\token.txt");` - был лишней строкой, файл открывался потоком и оставался открытым, тем самым не давая другим его использовать.

Убрал лишнюю строчку. Так-же упростил немного, переделал метод записи в файл.

```
using (StreamWriter token = new StreamWriter(path, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < token_lenght; i++)
    {
        token_result += token_param[rnd.Next(token_lng)];
        token.WriteLine(token_result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Набрала баллов чтобы смогла откомментировать \[^^]/. Переместите блок using над циклом for и поток на запись будет открываться лишь 1 раз вместо token_lenght раз. * фуф *

Comment: Ох, спасибочкии >_<. Так гараздо лучше смотрится =).

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.Default` зачем юникод? Чем вас UTF-8 не устраивает? `new StreamWriter(path)` - больше ничего не нужно.

Comment: Кстати "длина" пишется `length`, а не `lenght`.